# Oracle SQL select between two YEARs and MONTH

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL table with 4 columns. I am trying to get rows between the passed year and month.
The following query returns ZERO rows. Is this correct or should we use BETWEEN. Column data type is NUMBER AND not DATE. Following query return zero records.

```
select count( *) from TABLEA where refyear= 2020 AND refmonth in (1,2,3,4,5) AND 
refyear= 2019 AND refmonth in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

TABLEA
YEAR MONTH USERID NAME
2020   1    1      ABC
2020   2    1      ABC
2020   3    1      ABC
2020   4    1      ABC
2020   5    1      ABC2020
2019   1     1     ABC
2019   2     1     ABC
2019   3     1     ABC
2019   4     1     ABC
2019   5     1     ABC
2019   6     1     ABC
2019   7     1     ABC
2019   8     1     ABC
```

Comment: Is that sample data or the expected result? We need both anyway, a [mcve].

Comment: `where` condition passes over only those rows for which it evaluates to `true`. `A and B` is true if and only if both `A` and `B` is true. Obviosly, the same thing cannot be equal to different values at the same time: `where refyear= 2020 AND ... AND refyear= 2019 ...`. You need to use `between` for ranges

Answer (score 0):

I think the normal where contition would be:

```
where (refyear = 2020 AND refmonth in (1,2,3,4,5)) or
(refyear= 2019 AND refmonth in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

Still, I can't be certain that that is what you really want. The way you have written the logical condition it is normal to get no rows because you may not have at the same time refyear = 2020 and refyear= 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not correct as you are trying to get rows which have the `refyear` value simultaneously as `2019` and `2020` which is impossible and why you get no rows. If you want to get one or the other then you need to use `OR` and not `AND`.

---

If you are trying to get all the rows between August 2019 and May 2020 then:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM   TABLEA
WHERE  ( refyear = 2020 AND refmonth <= 5 )
OR     ( 2019 < refyear AND refyear < 2020 )
OR     ( refyear = 2019 AND refmonth >= 8 )
```

*Note: In this case, `OR ( 2019 < refyear AND refyear < 2020 )` will never be true so that line could be omitted but in the general case where the start and end years are not sequential then it would be required.*

---

If you did want all the years and months you list (and not a consecutive range) then  you can use an `IN` clause with multiple values:

```
SELECT count( *)
FROM   TABLEA
WHERE  (refyear, refmonth) IN (
         (2020, 1), (2020, 2), (2020, 3), (2020, 4), (2020, 5),
         (2019, 1), (2019, 2), (2019, 3), (2019, 4), (2019, 5), (2019, 6), (2019, 7), (2019, 8)
       )
```

or you can use your query and replace the `AND` with `OR`:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM   TABLEA
WHERE  ( refyear= 2020 AND refmonth in (1,2,3,4,5) )
OR     ( refyear= 2019 AND refmonth in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) )
```

*Note: in this case, the extra brackets are unnecessary and could be removed; but they are useful to help visualise the precedence of the `AND` and `OR` operators.*

Answer (score 0):

```
create table TABLEA (
YEAR integer,
MONTH integer,
USERID integer,
NAME varchar(50));

insert into tablea values (2020, 1, 1, 'ABC');
insert into tablea values (2020, 2, 1, 'ABC');
insert into tablea values (2020, 3, 1, 'ABC');
insert into tablea values (2020, 4, 1, 'ABC');
insert into tablea values (2020, 5, 1, 'ABC2020');
insert into tablea values (2019, 1, 1, 'ABC');
insert into tablea values (2019, 2, 1, 'ABC');
insert into tablea values (2019, 3, 1, 'ABC');
insert into tablea values (2019, 4, 1, 'ABC');
insert into tablea values (2019, 5, 1, 'ABC');
insert into tablea values (2019, 6, 1, 'ABC');
insert into tablea values (2019, 7, 1, 'ABC');
insert into tablea values (2019, 8, 1, 'ABC');

select * from tablea;

 year | month | userid |  name
------+-------+--------+---------
 2020 |     1 |      1 | ABC
 2020 |     2 |      1 | ABC
 2020 |     3 |      1 | ABC
 2020 |     4 |      1 | ABC
 2020 |     5 |      1 | ABC2020
 2019 |     1 |      1 | ABC
 2019 |     2 |      1 | ABC
 2019 |     3 |      1 | ABC
 2019 |     4 |      1 | ABC
 2019 |     5 |      1 | ABC
 2019 |     6 |      1 | ABC
 2019 |     7 |      1 | ABC
 2019 |     8 |      1 | ABC
```

If you want to have the result of multiple selects in one query result you could try this :

```
select count(*)
from tablea
where year=2020
and month in (1,2,3,4,5)
union
select count(*)
from tablea
where year= 2019
and month in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

  count
-------
     5
     8
```